# SELECT SUM and COUNT, FROM different tables on same row, PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I got 3 tables, **transactions**, **clubs** and **clients**, a Club can have only one salesman, and each Client can belong to only one Club, the clients make payments in the **transactions** table.

I'm trying to get a list of all Salesman, how many payments per Club and the total amount of payment per Club on a specific date.

I only get one row, with the first salesman, and the total for everyone, don't know how to get each row with the totals of each individual Salesman. Thank you for your time.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|                transactions                |
+--------------------------------------------+
| id_transaction | date | amount | client_id |
+----------------+------+--------+-----------+

+------------------------------+
|            clients           |
+------------------------------+
| id_client | name | club_name |
+-----------+------+-----------+

+-----------------------------------+
|               clubs               |
+-----------------------------------+
| id_club | name_club | name_seller |
+---------+-----------+-------------+

SELECT 
   transactions.amount,
   clients.id_client,
   clubs.club_name,
   club.name_seller,
   SUM(transactions.amount) AS sum_amount,
   COUNT(transactions.amount) AS count_amount,
   club.name_seller AS salesman
FROM transactions, members, clubs
WHERE transactions.date = '$date' 
AND clients.id_client = transactions.client_id 
AND client.club_name = clubs.name_club 


 <th>Salesman</th>
 <th>Club Name</th>
 <th>Number of Transactions</th>
 <th>Total amount</th>   

 $output.='<td>'.$row['salesman'].'</td>';
 $output.='<td>'.$row['club_name'].'</td>';
 $output.='<td>'.$row['COUNT(amount)'].'</td>';
 $output.='<td>'.$row['SUM(amount)'].'</td>';
```

This is what I'm trying, Example:

> Salesman - Club name   -  Number of Transactions - Total amount
>         Bill     -  TennisClub -           5             -     5000 
>         Bill     -  Golf Club  -           7             -     7000 
>         Joe      -  Pool Cub   -           2             -     2000

Comment: I can't see how you arrive at 5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **Group By** statement in your query ( If you want salesman based, You can put salesman id )

I think, you have changed the table structure names before posting the question. So, I can't understood the Primary & Foreign key's.